# Oracle SQL return sum of multiple across tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Farily new to SQL and the IT world, and always do a lot of work before asking for help but this time I am stumped.

I have three tables:

[image]

So I am trying to update the "payment_owed" table by doing the following:
For each customer, get the food_id and quantity, then using the food_id multiply the quantity by the cost.

The best I have done this far is a natural join on the tables, and attempting to sum the quantity * cost for each ID

My understanding for updating a specific customer:

```
update customer
set payment_owed = (select <quantity>) * (select <cost>)
where cust_no = 1;
```

If im not on the right forum or there's a better place to ask these questions let me know, thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I removed all the product specific tags. Please add back the one that you are actually using.

Comment: On a sidenote: You mention **natural joins**. My advice: **Don't ever use them!** They are prone to crash queries once columns get added to the tables. I don't know why natural joins were ever introduced in the standard. That was a bad idea from the start.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, thank you for the advice! I did not know that, I'll make it a practice to look for disadvantages of methods before I blindly use them, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
update customer
set payment_owed = (SELECT SUM(o.cost*s.quantity) 
                   FROM order o JOIN session s ON s.food_id = o.food_id         
                   WHERE s.cust_no = customer.cust_no)
where cust_no = 1;
```

Anyway will you update it after every change on table? How about using view like:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT cust_no, SUM(o.cost*s.quantity) 
FROM order o 
JOIN session s ON s.food_id = o.food_id
GROUP BY cust_no;
```

Comment: A view is great, or a computed column!

Comment: I'd change this from `WHERE s.cust_no = 1` to `WHERE s.cust_no = customer.cust_no`, so it still works when the main query's where clause gets changed or removed..

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, the first version before edit was using correlated  subquery too. I will change to original version.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and I apologise for all the mistakes I made asking this question, I'll be better at it next time! It's exactly what I was looking for! thank you very much for your time everyone